# Most efficient way sort a char array by code point? (Ordinal sort)

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, optimization

I want to sort a char array as efficiently as possible, i.e. with minimal CPU usage, memory allocs and garbage collection overhead. My naive first attempt is this simple example:

Assume the array already exists, e.g.

```
char[] word = "hello world".ToCharArray();
```

Optimise this naive approach:

```
Array.Sort(word, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Actually I was surprised this worked since it's using a string comparer to compare chars, so I'm suspecting there is a conversion from char to string going on inside the comparer, which would be sub-optimal in terms of CPU usage and garbage collection, etc.

Assuming I wanted to perform this sort as efficiently as possible, what is the best approach?

Right now my fall-back is to use something like:

```
List<char> wordChars = "hello world".ToList();
wordChars.Sort((char x, char y) => 
{
    return (int)x - (int)y;
});
```

I'd prefer not to have the overhead of a List for each word though. The other option is to write my own quicksort routine!

P.S. To pre-empt the usual barrage of challenges - Yes I really do want to sort a char array by code point, and yes I do need to make it optimal!! The faster the better. Thanks!

---

For the record here is a strongly typed char quick sort...

```
public static class CharSort
{
    public static void QuickSort(char[] arr)
    {
        QuickSort(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
    }

    private static void QuickSort(char[] arr, int left, int right)
    {
        do
        {
            int p = left;
            int q = right;
            char val = arr[p + (q - p >> 1)];
            do
            {
                if(p < arr.Length)
                {
                    if(val - arr[p] > 0)
                    {
                        p++;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                while (q >= 0 && (val - arr[q] < 0)) 
                {
                    q--;
                }

                if(p > q) {
                    break;
                }

                if(p < q)
                {
                    char num3 = arr[p];
                    arr[p] = arr[q];
                    arr[q] = num3;
                }
                p++;
                q--;
            }
            while(p <= q);
            if(q - left <= right - p)
            {
                if(left < q) {
                    QuickSort(arr, left, q);
                }
                left = p;
            }
            else
            {
                if(p < right) {
                    QuickSort(arr, p, right);
                }
                right = q;
            }
        }
        while(left < right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your benchmark codes and the goal you want to achive so that we know what to do to avoid annecessary comments..

Comment: Hmm, fair enough, however my instinct is that the path of least resistance there is to write a strongly typed quicksort method - I can do that in less time than writing benchmark code! My main issue is I don't know what garbage and casting overhead the standard approaches have, so I'd like to get an expert opinion, otherwise I can simply avoid them in this instance.

Comment: BTW: `The other option is to write my own quicksort routine!` I would like to see it.

Comment: `I can do that in less time than writing benchmark code` Without it how would you know which one is better. Let's say I posted a smart answer. Would you trust a strangers code just because it looks good?

Comment: So I'm clear, with "hello world" your expected result of the sort is " dehllloorw"?

Comment: Correct. "helloworld" becomes "dehllloorw"

Comment: What about the space character in "hello world"? In my last comment, the space character is the first character.

Comment: @redcalx OK, Let's assume I say `var s = "helloworld".OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();` is the fastest. What is your critria to measure it?

Comment: Speed of the code being profiled is only one factor. The resulting memory alloc and GC 'churn' has knock-on effects on the process as a whole that's I'd prefer to avoid. So e.g. that specific approach creates a new array and copies into it, so there are at least two avoidable subroutines being executed.

Comment: @redcalx have you profiled it? **Intuitions** may not be always correct. Maybe the sorting algorithm is very fast and creating a new array is a tiny cost (BTW: I am not saying this is correct). What I see is you are waiting some authority saying "do this", whithout showing any effort to measure which one is **really** corrrect.

Comment: `What I see is you are waiting some authority saying "do this"` - I'm looking for options to investigate further. It's in my nature to question everything to the Nth degree, hence the reason I paused and came to SO rather than doing Array.Sort(...).

Comment: OK, It seems you will choose one because "you **liked** it better". Good Luck.

Comment: Clash of cultures I suspect. The nub of the issue (for me) is that the higher the level of abstraction the more unknowns there are, and hence the greater the probability of some extremely sub-optimal corner case. In comparison to, e.g. quicksort, which may not be *the* optimal solution, but it is near-optimal and is well understood and therefore has limited scope for going wrong, i.e. worst case is O(n) and no array allocs and copies. Corner cases kill (I just made that up :)

Answer (score 1):

List.Sort is probably better than what you will be able to write in a short time, it works like this [[see]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx):

- If the partition size is fewer than 16 elements, it uses an insertion
  sort algorithm.
- If the number of partitions exceeds 2 * LogN, where N is the range of
  the input array, it uses a Heapsort algorithm.
- Otherwise, it uses a Quicksort algorithm.

I imagine it might be faster to simply count the occurrence of each character, but this can get tricky with Unicode code points (surrogate pairs).  If all you are concerned with is common English characters (ASCII range), you can just allocate an array the size of the range of characters (127), loop thru the string using the character value as the index and increment.  If you really need the actual string you can reconstitute it by creating a string buffer and filling it with the counts of each non-zero character count, in index order.

One thing worth mentioning is you need to ask yourself what is "fast enough".  Clearly, there is a reason you feel that "string".ToArray().Sort() isn't fast enough.  That might indicate that an approach other than a sort might be needed.  Hard to say given the limited details.

Comment: Thanks. My primary motivation was avoiding any boxing/casting, since Array.Sort() isn't generic, and the StringComparer appears to not have any char based methods on it, which suggests that each comparison is casting from char to string. On reflection my question is more about avoiding any really obviously wasteful things like that, which could easily use 10x more CPU than a strongly typed quicksort. Interesting to see the heuristics on the built in Sorting - not seen those before.

Comment: If you use a linq based approach |new String("gzdefghs3i".OrderBy(x => x).ToArray())| no StringComparer or boxing should be involved.  The OrderBy() method will enumerate and sort using the default comparison (<,>,=) which is ordinal, which depending on the culture/lang may or may not be considered an alphabetic sort.  ToArray forces the linq expression to run (actually creates the array) and the string constructor copies the array into a new string.  Might be faster to do var x = "gzdefghs3i".ToCharArray(); x.Sort(); and have less allocations